# Stacking keywords on top of each other - poor style?

Tags: c#, programming-practices, syntax

I have always wondered about this, especially in C/Java style languages. For example, consider the first 3 lines of this C# code:

```
lock (serviceLock)
using (var client = new ServiceClient())
try
{
    // Do something
    client.DoSomething();
}

catch (System.ServiceModel.FaultException ex)
{
    // Handle error
    addLog(ex.ToString());
}
```

This usage has always seemed somewhat questionable to me. However, the alternative is not very practical either (3+ levels deep of indentation for a service call). Apart from pure aesthetics, is there any practical reason to add or not to add the extra brackets in this case?

Comment: What seems questionable here is making a service call while holding a lock!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `lock` and `using` blocks are for programmer convenience, but are not required. If you find *less indented* code easier to read. You can write the same thing using the *non-code-block* version of the same C# features.

```
Monitor.Enter(serviceLock);
var client = new ServiceClient();
try
{
    client.DoSomething();
}
catch(FaultException ex)
{
    addLog(ex.ToString());
}
finally
{
    Monitor.Exit(serviceLock);
    client.Dispose();
}
```

The above does the same thing, but there is no readability issue or confusion as to what it's doing.

The alternative approach is to use *blocks* and break everything into separate functions.

```
public function foo()
{
    lock(serviceLock)
    {
        fooService();
    }
}

private function fooService()
{
    using(ServiceClient client = new ServiceClient())
    {
        fooClientTry(client);
    }
}

private function fooClientTry(ServiceClient client)
{
    try
    {
        fooClient(client);
    }
    catch(System.ServiceModel.FaultException ex)
    {
        addLog(ex.ToString());
    }
}

private function fooClient(ServiceClient client)
{
    // work....
}
```

I prefer the above approach. It looks like a lot more work/code but it's easier to maintain because each function performs a single task. When you get into multiple nested blocks this approach keeps everything only a few indentations.

Comment: +1 for `Monitor`. It's less idiomatic but certainly good to have it up your sleeve

Comment: The statement that your code "does the same thing" as a `lock` statement is incorrect.  Section 8.12 of the C# language specification describes the code that is generated by the compiler:  it calls the `Monitor` methods in a specific way to avoid potential race conditions.

Comment: -1.  `lock(x)` and `using` were created to eliminate the ugliness of `try...finally`.  They handle the acquisition and release reliably in a single place.  It is all too easy to forget to release a manually acquired resource.

Comment: The `client.Dispose()` call [can throw an exception](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa355056(v=vs.110).aspx), which would mean that the `Monitor.Exit(serviceLock);` statement would not execute. I don't think this is equivalent to the original code. (I don't like the style of the original code, though, and would prefer the indentation.)

Comment: `Monitor` is what the MSDN says to use if you don't want to use `using`, and the code is their example. I never use `Monitor` but I offered two options. Break it down into smaller functions or use `Monitor`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/de0542zz

Comment: I agree that using Monitor.Enter and Monitor.Exit is equivalent to the lock statement, but the lock statement also implicitly encloses everything, including the using block (or the `try { ... } finally { client.Dispose(); }` if you prefer) inside of a `try { ... }`. Your first code example is only equivalent to the original if `client.Dispose()` does not throw an exception. However, if it does throw an exception, then Monitor.Exit will not be called, which is different behavior than the original `lock (...) using (...) ...` code.

Comment: @Dr.Wily'sApprentice I swapped the two lines. Problem solved.

Comment: @MathewFoscarini Ok, that works, since we can be very sure that Monitor.Exit won't throw an exception.

Answer (score 14):

I would strongly suggested you use three levels of nested indentation. When I look at this code quickly, I only see the catch(){} block, see a match try{} block, and ignore the fact that there is a lock and using statement. Now, when I look at the code more carefully, I noticed that there are keywords hanging out above the try, but their scope may not be immediately apparent to me--are they just for the try block, or are they for the try/catch statement? If you need to add code at some point, I can almost guarantee someone will miss the lock or using statements (the same reason why most coding standards I've seen prohibit placing only one line after an if statement and not using curly braces). I would go with the most specific code, which is three levels of indentation using proper brackets so that the scope is immediately understandable.

If the indentation bothers you that much, I suggest using 2 spaces instead of tabs (which should be an option in your IDE). It's something I picked up at my job, and have really fallen for as I use it. It's much more concise than having a two inch gap because you indented four times.

Comment: I would suggest using caution regarding changing the tab spacing options in your IDE; all team members should use the same settings, otherwise your code will become a mess of different styles (some code indented with 2 spaces, some with 4, some with tabs). Otherwise, +1 for this post. I find alternative styles that attempt to condense code to be harder to read (i.e. takes longer for my brain to parse), since I can't take advantage of the semantic cues that conventional code structure/style provides.

Answer (score 12):

I'd say I'm against it. I'll come around and add some code after `try...catch` without noticing that I should have extended the scope of `lock`.

And, more importantly, **this version doesn't really reduce indentation!**

It only **hides** it. Deep nesting is primarily a logical problem, not an aesthetical one.

The fact that we see it as ugly is a result of it being a bad programming practice; not the other way round.

(Aesthetics by itself is relative - eg. [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/118717/29029) highly upvoted answer claims that *"deeply nested structural statements – "arrowheads" – were, in languages like Pascal, once seen as beautiful code."*)

Three levels is still fine, but if you reach - say - seven levels, does removing braces from `lock` and `using`, and de-indenting, address the issue really?

Quite the contrary, it desensitizes the developer to the problem, thus reducing the chance someone will go ahead and refactor the thing.

Answer (score 6):

For a dissenting opinion, I rather like this practice with one significant change.

```
lock (serviceLock) using (var client = new ServiceClient()) try
{
    // Do something
    client.DoSomething();
}
catch (System.ServiceModel.FaultException ex)
{
    // Handle error
    addLog(ex.ToString());
}
```

By not stacking, it forces the eye to read all the way across as one long statement. If the line is too long or does not read well, then you know you want to reorganize the logic.

I often do this with double for-loops and for-loops with try catch blocks.

```
for (int i = 0; i < x.Length; ++i) for (int j = 0; j < x[i].Length; ++j) try
{
    // each cell in a ragged matrix: x[i][j]
}
catch (/* … */)
{
    // exception in one cell allowing other cells to be processed.
}
```

Above all else, clarity is the most important thing. If you are rigid with any style, you will end up with ugly and unreadable code in some cases. Be flexible in a way that allows you to highlight the logic. If you don't know if something is clear, then have your co-developers to look at it. Ask them what the code does without explaining it to them.

Comment: I like your first example but not your second.

Answer (score 3):

I have no problem with stacking the locks and usings, but the try-catch should be wrapped in braces. That will require you to think what the scope of the `using` statement is in this context.

```
lock (serviceLock)
using (var client = new ServiceClient())
{
  try
  {
      client.DoSomething();
  }    
  catch (System.ServiceModel.FaultException ex)
  {
      addLog(ex.ToString());
  }
}
```

I stack keywords all the time (mostly `using` bit also stuff like `fixed` and `unsafe`) because sometimes I would be adding six or more braces. There's no way you can read that at a glance and tell which brace matches which. Also it increases the risk that the code for your method won't fit on the screen. That's not good for readability either.

Answer (score 1):

The rule is simple. Indentation needs to be consistent with scope. The `lock` is applying until the end of the `catch` block and needs to look like it. I'm not familiar with the `using` keyword in C# but from your code the same rule looks to apply.

Comment: You confused the `using` **directive** (the equivalent of Java's imports - and in C# you can't put it anywhere else than the top of the file, either) with the `using` **statement** (which is what the OP used). Entirely different beasts. See msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx and msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943542/using-keyword-in-java

Comment: Yeah, he is, but +1 for "_The lock is applying until the end of the catch block and needs to look like it._", and for the fact that he probably would have said the same for `using` if it weren't for C#'s silly dual uses of the keyword.

Comment: @KonradMorawski fixed (weeks later)